# EIPHTTPProtocolExceptionPeer exception using PutBlock with array of bytes all set to zero

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, azure-blob-storage

Using Delphi XE2 Update 3 I'm having a problem uploading a block of zero bytes to Azure. When I say zero bytes, I mean an array of bytes with each element set to zero (it's not zero length).

For example:

```
var
  ConInfo: TAzureConnectionInfo;
  RespInfo: TCloudResponseInfo;
  BlobService: TAzureBlobService;
  Content: TBytes;
  MD5: String;
  Hasher: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
begin
  ConInfo:=TAzureConnectionInfo.Create(self);
  ConInfo.AccountName:='YOUR ACCOUNT NAME';
  ConInfo.AccountKey:='YOUR ACCOUNT KEY';
  ConInfo.Protocol:='http';

  BlobService:=TAzureBlobService.Create(ConInfo);    
  RespInfo:=TCloudResponseInfo.Create;

  SetLength(Content, 1048576); // 1 MByte
  FillMemory(@Content[0], 1048576, 0); // << --- fill it with anything except 0 and it works

  Hasher:=TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  MD5:=Data.Cloud.CloudAPI.EncodeBytes64(Hasher.HashBytes(Content));
  Hasher.Free;

  BlobService.PutBlock('CONTAINER NAME', 'BLOB NAME', MD5, Content, MD5, '', RespInfo);
```

If the above code is run then an exception is raised on the call to PutBlock:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class
>   EIPHTTPProtocolExceptionPeer with message 'HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed
>   to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization
>   header is formed correctly including the signature.'.

But if you change the **FillMemory** line so that it fills it with 1's (or anything but zero), then it works without error. Why?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbelievably, it seems that the problem is the block ID value of **ttgbNgpWctgMJ0MPORU+LA==**

If you use it as a block ID then you get that error.

Comment: Actually, it is a bug in TCloudService.URLEncodeValue(). It does not URL encode plus signs (+) when it should.